# Options.txt file hearthstone

Tags: wine, 15.04, playonlinux

I finally opened Hearthstone,played a few games without any problem, but I made a critical mistake, I put the graphics quality in High and closed the game. Now, when I open Hearthstone using wine, playonlinux and the battlenet app appears a black screen forever, I need help with this. 
Thank you all.

My wine current version is 1.6.2 (the latest stable release).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can edit `~/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/prefixname/Users/username/AppData/Local/Blizzard/Hearthstone/options.txt`. If you don't know what to edit i suppose you can just delete it and the game should generate a new one with default options once you launch it, back it up for an insurance though.

Comment: I can't find that folder.. Searching everywhere and I can't find that file, Idk what the problem is, this is so annoying :(

Comment: Please edit the question, specifying the current wine version, and try looking into `c:\windows\profiles\<username>\Application Data`. I have read some versions use the old win95 directory tree.